# Slim framework dealing with multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, slim

I have been working on a slim project and i can now retrieve data from one table called “shows”.

I can apply all the http functions: get, post, put and delete on the table “shows”

However i have two other tables called “cues” and “crews” connected to table “shows” by foriegn keys.

The question is, as this is my very first slim webapp, how can i apply the http functions on these two other tables? And should i create multiple routes.php for every table?

Is the right way to keep all routes in one routes.php file regardless to how big the project was?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In general, your routes should meet the requirements of your application, not your database tables. Slim doesn't dictate your application structure so you can organise you routes however you like. Personally, I think a single routes.php is a good starting place.